# Qt Installer Framework, installer crashes when having multiple elevated operations

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, symlink, qt-installer

This is the first app that I'm trying to deploy.
I need the installer to establish a symlink with one of the installed files as well as adding the user to a different group. I'm currently using `component.addElevatedOperation("CreateLink", <linkPath>, <targetPath>)` and `component.addElevatedOperation("Execute", "usermod -a -G dialout id")` 
to accomplish this. 
The installer builds successfully with the IFW's `binarycreator`.
The problem occurs when running the installer. If I try to install the component containing these operation, the installer freezes. It freezes right after I've entered the sudo password. How do I get the installer to successfully run these commands?